# configure kafka queues in java classes instead of yml

Tags: yaml, microservices, spring-cloud

Is any "valid on fly" way to configure `spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka` of `org.springframework.cloud` queues between microservices. I am looking for more readable configuration than for example:

source `payment-service.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        payments-for-supliers-out-0: # must be the same in EventEmitter
          destination: payment-for-suplier-events
        payments-from-customers-out-0: # must be the same in EventEmitter
          destination: payment-from-customer-events
```

receiver `supply-service.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: paymentForSuplierEventsConsumer
    stream:
      bindings:
        paymentForSuplierEventsConsumer-in-0:
          destination: payment-for-suplier-events
          group: supliers-001
```

receiver `customer-service.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: paymentFromCustomerEventsConsumer
    stream:
      bindings:
        paymentFromCustomerEventsConsumer-in-0:
          destination: payment-from-customer-events
          group: customers-001
```

in my opinion, it is easy to lose the hierarchy in each service yml (if more than one queues to listen), but in the spring cloud configuration java class I would have current validation according to the IDE java compiler, at least.